# Does 0x have websocket api on polygon now?

Tags: 0x

How can I get 0x limit orders list? Does 0x have websocket api on Polygon now? As I know before,0x Websocket API only supportted mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

currently the 0x websocket API is only on mainnet. You can use the `/orderbook` endpoint of the REST API to retrieve limit orders: https://0x.org/docs/api#orderbook.